# TextView click event in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

Suppose I have a textView "Register [here]". How do I make [here] clickable that goes to a certain webpage? Thanks so much

Comment: You can use textView.setOnClickListener() for this

Comment: And also use 2 textviews in your UI and make the second one clickable

Comment: But how do I make only that certain part "here" of the string clickable?

Comment: Oh ya, that could be one way. Thanks :)

Comment: @ Swr7der : Using 2 textview is not proper way.. As you can use spannable text for same.

Comment: I got it, I used to use like that, but that's not the proper way. Thanks for your valuable answer @Beena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clickable span for it...

```
 private void setClickableSpan(){
    String text1="Register ";
    String text2=" [here]";

    String mainText=text1+text2;
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(mainText);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpanTerms = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {

            // Your code of navigating to webpage
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.colorHintLogin));
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpanTerms, text1.length(), text1.length()+text2.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);




    yourTextView.setText(ss);
    textAcceptTermAndCondition.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    yourTextView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but i am getting error in `R.color.colorHintLogin` . What is colorHintLogin ?

Comment: Also just for confirmation, I should add this part inside `onCreate()` right?

Comment: @sabiha taskin : It is the color of my textview text. You can simply ignore this line or give any color from your color.xml file to it as per your UI.

Comment: @sabihataskin : Yes. After initialisation of your textview

Comment: on execution of the application it says my `setClickableSpan` is unused. :(

Comment: You need to call this method 

`setClickableSpan()`

from your `onCreate()` after initialisation of your textview.